# Knockoutjs: Not working in IE7

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, internet-explorer-7

Please find my code in the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/vdcUA/55/

This is not working in IE7 or more specifically IE8-Compatible mode

I have used the knockoutjs plugin in the code.

Please suggest how to over come this ...

Thanks, Naveen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like IE7 requires a `tbody` to insert/remove rows via JavaScript.  Adding a `tbody` tag to your table and putting your template binding on it works properly:  http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/P6aDk/