# knockoutjs foreach not working in IE 7 & IE 8

Tags: knockout.js

I am new to working with knockout and i have worked on sample application that displays array object in a tabular format using foreach. Data is getting rendered correctly in IE9, firefox, chrome, safari browsers but data is not getting rendered in IE 7 & IE 8 browsers. As per [knockoutjs site](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/browser-support.html), they claim knockout works in IE 6+ browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/chiru_neeru/sbbNu/8/

FYI: I have referenced 2.0.0 knockout.js & jquery1.7.1.js files in my sample application. My sample code in the above jsfiddle url also not getting rendered when i run it but the same code is working correctly in my sample application.

Can anybody guide me how to make the above sample application works in IE 7 & IE 8 browsers? I followed the instructions given in [Knockoutjs: Not working in IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7231887/knockoutjs-not-working-in-ie7) but it is not working in my sample application scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you open and close all of your `span` tags properly.  They need opening and closing tags like: `<span data-bind="text:'blah'"></span>`

http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/aq9mE/